# unresolved external <function name> referenced from <path of the cpp file using that function>

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to create a dll in borland c++ 5.02 for example **dir.dll** it uses the functions of other dll called **bmi.dll** which i have created earlier.

But, the problem is i was getting the errors **unresolved external  referenced from**   where ever i use the functions of bmi.dll.I have given correctly the path to the lib file of the **bmi.lib**. please help with this issue why i was getting this error

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Can you post example code how the missing function is declared? It may not be correctly exported, or the declaration may not be correct.

You can also use the DependencyWalker tool to examine bmi.dll and see what functions are publicly available there.

Comment: Did you actually add bmi.lib itself to the dir.dll project, or use a `#pragma comment(lib, bmi.lib)` statement in your code? It is not enough to dimply point at the folder where bmi.lib is located, the linker still needs to know that bmi.lib is to be linked into the final DLL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added the dir.dll to the code which is using it and specified the path of the bmi.lib to the library path(edit local options --> directories --> library)